# Confusion about creating data files in custom locations

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 12, I created a new tablespace in a Non-default directory(not in $PGDATA), but I found that the same size file was automatically created inside the default folder($PGDATA).

I remember that in the 9 version, a soft link was automatically created in the default location to point to the custom tablespace folder.

```
[root@freelab PG_12_201909212]# du -sh /postgres/pg_tblspc/16385/PG_12_201909212; du -sh /pgdata/music/PG_12_201909212
4.3G    /postgres/pg_tblspc/16385/PG_12_201909212    ---default tablespace
4.3G    /pgdata/music/PG_12_201909212   ---new directory
```

This situation causes the default space to consume space as the custom space grows.

Would you like to ask, is this an operational problem or a new feature?

The detailed operation process is as follows：

```
postgres=#  create tablespace tbs_music location '/pgdata/music';
CREATE TABLESPACE
postgres=# \db++
                                     List of tablespaces
    Name    |  Owner   |   Location    | Access privileges | Options |  Size   | Description
------------+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------
 pg_default | postgres |               |                   |         | 24 MB   |
 pg_global  | postgres |               |                   |         | 623 kB  |
 tbs_music  | postgres | /pgdata/music |                   |         | 0 bytes |
(3 rows)

postgres=#  create database music tablespace  tbs_music;
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# \db++
                                     List of tablespaces
    Name    |  Owner   |   Location    | Access privileges | Options |  Size   | Description
------------+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------
 pg_default | postgres |               |                   |         | 24 MB   |
 pg_global  | postgres |               |                   |         | 623 kB  |
 tbs_music  | postgres | /pgdata/music |                   |         | 8057 kB |
(3 rows)


[root@freelab 16401]# pwd
/pgdata/music/PG_12_201909212/16401
[root@freelab 16401]# ls
112        14029      14052     2603      2611      2651  2675  2704      2840_vm   3394_fsm  3541_vm   3605      4153  5002
113        14031      14054     2603_fsm  2612      2652  2678  2753      2841      3394_vm   3542      3606      4154  548
1247       14032      14056     2603_vm   2612_fsm  2653  2679  2753_fsm  2995      3395      3574      3607      4155  549
1247_fsm   14032_fsm  1417      2604      2612_vm   2654  2680  2753_vm   2996      3429      3575      3608      4156  6102
1247_vm    14032_vm   1418      2605      2613      2655  2681  2754      3079      3430      3576      3609      4157  6104
1249       14034      174       2605_fsm  2615      2656  2682  2755      3079_fsm  3431      3596      3712      4158  6106
1249_fsm   14036      175       2605_vm   2615_fsm  2657  2683  2756      3079_vm   3433      3597      3764      4159  6110
1249_vm    14037      2187      2606      2615_vm   2658  2684  2757      3080      3439      3598      3764_fsm  4160  6111
1255       14037_fsm  2224      2606_fsm  2616      2659  2685  2830      3081      3440      3599      3764_vm   4161  6112
1255_fsm   14037_vm   2328      2606_vm   2616_fsm  2660  2686  2831      3085      3455      3600      3766      4162  6113
1255_vm    14039      2336      2607      2616_vm   2661  2687  2832      3118      3456      3600_fsm  3767      4163  6117
1259       14041      2337      2607_fsm  2617      2662  2688  2833      3119      3456_fsm  3600_vm   3997      4164  826
1259_fsm   14042      2579      2607_vm   2617_fsm  2663  2689  2834      3164      3456_vm   3601      4143      4165  827
1259_vm    14042_fsm  2600      2608      2617_vm   2664  2690  2835      3256      3466      3601_fsm  4144      4166  828
14022      14042_vm   2600_fsm  2608_fsm  2618      2665  2691  2836      3257      3467      3601_vm   4145      4167  pg_filenode.map
14022_fsm  14044      2600_vm   2608_vm   2618_fsm  2666  2692  2837      3258      3468      3602      4146      4168  PG_VERSION
14022_vm   14046      2601      2609      2618_vm   2667  2693  2838      3350      3501      3602_fsm  4147      4169
14024      14047      2601_fsm  2609_fsm  2619      2668  2696  2838_fsm  3351      3502      3602_vm   4148      4170
14026      14047_fsm  2601_vm   2609_vm   2619_fsm  2669  2699  2838_vm   3379      3503      3603      4149      4171
14027      14047_vm   2602      2610      2619_vm   2670  2701  2839      3380      3534      3603_fsm  4150      4172
14027_fsm  14049      2602_fsm  2610_fsm  2620      2673  2702  2840      3381      3541      3603_vm   4151      4173
14027_vm   14051      2602_vm   2610_vm   2650      2674  2703  2840_fsm  3394      3541_fsm  3604      4152      4174


postgres=# ALTER DATABASE music SET TABLESPACE tbs_music;
ALTER DATABASE

postgres=# \c music
You are now connected to database "music" as user "postgres".
music=#   CREATE TABLE test1
music-# (
music(#   id integer,
music(#   test integer
music(# )
music-# tablespace tbs_music;
CREATE TABLE


music=# select pg_relation_filepath('test1');
            pg_relation_filepath
---------------------------------------------
 pg_tblspc/16385/PG_12_201909212/16401/16402
(1 row)


music=# insert into test1 SELECT generate_series(1,1000000) as key, (random()*(10^3))::integer;
INSERT 0 1000000


[root@freelab 16401]# du -sh /postgres/pg_tblspc/16385/PG_12_201909212/16401/16402
35M     /postgres/pg_tblspc/16385/PG_12_201909212/16401/16402

[root@freelab 16401]# du -sh /pgdata/music/PG_12_201909212/16401/16402
35M     /pgdata/music/PG_12_201909212/16401/16402


music=# \db+
                                    List of tablespaces
    Name    |  Owner   |   Location    | Access privileges | Options |  Size  | Description
------------+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------------
 pg_default | postgres |               |                   |         | 24 MB  |
 pg_global  | postgres |               |                   |         | 623 kB |
 tbs_music  | postgres | /pgdata/music |                   |         | 43 MB  |
(3 rows)
```

Referring to the idea of Raj Verma, I retested and found that there is a soft link to the custom location at the directory level of pg_tblspc, and only the custom directory space is growing after generating new data.

```
[root@freelab pg_tblspc]# ls -lrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 13 Jan 31 02:53 16385 -> /pgdata/music
[root@freelab pg_tblspc]# pwd
/postgres/pg_tblspc

[root@freelab ~]#  du -sh /postgres;du -sh /pgdata/
921M    /postgres
43M     /pgdata/

A new table was created.


[root@freelab ~]#  du -sh /postgres;du -sh /pgdata/
921M    /postgres
107M    /pgdata/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does create a symlink for non default tablespace created inside PG.

```
postgres=# \db++
                                 List of tablespaces
Name    |  Owner  |    Location     | Access privileges | Options |  Size   | 
Description
------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+------- 
--+-------------
newspace   | raj | /tmp/pgtblspace |                   |         | 7650 kB |
pg_default | raj |                 |                   |         | 4085 MB |
pg_global  | raj |                 |                   |         | 574 kB  |
(3 rows)
```

and the space location being "/tmp/pgtblespace" its created a symlink in the pg_tablespace directory.

```
lrwx------  1 raj  admin    15B Feb  4 09:50 41852 -> /tmp/pgtblspace
```

Now in your case can you login to the pg server and check the space location details for the tablespaces by doing "\db++"?

This would clarify as to what really is the location of the tblspaces.

**New additions/Edits**

alright so i did try to replicate your situation but unfortunately it did not replicate. 
although i did go through the source code for a bit, looks like you are hitting a bug here.
you might want to drop the tablespace and create a new one.
i created multiple tablespaces for pg12 but did not see this problem.
drop the current tblspaces and clear out the pg_tblspace folder and the custom tblspace folder as well.
create new tablespace with the custom folder location and should be fine to use.
see below:

```
test=# \db++
                                    List of tablespaces
    Name     |  Owner   |            Location             | Access privileges | Description
-------------+----------+---------------------------------+-------------------+-------------
 pg_default  | postgres |                                 |                   |
 pg_global   | postgres |                                 |                   |
 tblspc_raj  | postgres | /var/lib/pgsql/12/tblspace_new  |                   |
 tblspc_raj1 | postgres | /var/lib/pgsql/12/tblspace_new1 |                   |
 tblspc_raj2 | postgres | /var/lib/pgsql/12               |                   |
 tblspc_raj3 | postgres | /var/lib/pgsql/12/tblspace_new2 |                   |
 tbs_music   | postgres | /var/lib/pgsql/music            |                   |
(7 rows)
```

Also the folder structure for the custom location looks like this:

```
bash-4.2$ ls -l
total 8
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 30 05:31 backups
drwx------. 20 postgres postgres 4096 Feb  4 00:00 data
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres  927 Dec  4 04:49 initdb.log
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 Feb  3 23:49 PG_12_201909212
drwx------.  3 postgres postgres   28 Feb  3 23:44 tblspace_new
drwx------.  3 postgres postgres   28 Feb  3 23:48 tblspace_new1
drwx------.  3 postgres postgres   28 Feb  3 23:52 tblspace_new2
bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql/12
```

and the one inside the pg_tblspace looks like this:

```
-bash-4.2$ ll
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 30 Feb  3 23:44 16391 -> /var/lib/pgsql/12/tblspace_new
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 31 Feb  3 23:48 16395 -> /var/lib/pgsql/12/tblspace_new1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 17 Feb  3 23:49 16396 -> /var/lib/pgsql/12
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 31 Feb  3 23:52 16397 -> /var/lib/pgsql/12/tblspace_new2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 20 Feb  3 23:55 16400 -> /var/lib/pgsql/music
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 14 Feb  4 00:01 16402 -> /var/lib/pgsql
-bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_tblspc
```

Comment: Thank you, Raj Verma, I have added detailed operations in the original text above. Please refer.

Comment: let me know if that works, this most definitely is hitting some bug at the level when you have the default table space defined. I just added my edits above.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The experience on this version of 9 before this operation is the same as the test case provided by you, but this incredible situation appears in 12 at present, it is estimated that it is related to the bug.

Comment: Raj Verma，thank you very much for your help.I also tested and verified，you are right.My previous test problem appeared in the wrong location of the detection path.The test method has been updated in the original text above.

Answer (score 0):

> This situation causes the default space to consume space as the custom space grows.

It does not.  Your example shows it does not.  pg_default does not grow, while tbs_music does.

> du -sh /postgres/pg_tblspc/16385/PG_12_201909212

`du` is following the symlink, and providing the size of the directory contents it finds there. If you ran `du -sh /postgres/pg_tblspc/16385` with no trailing slash, you would see the size is zero.  All of the size reposes at the symlinked-to location, not at the symlinked-from location.